# remove leading characters from each row in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have column that looks like the following

```
name
http:name
http:name
http:name
```

I want to remove `http:` from all the rows.

Is this the best way to do this?

```
UPDATE Table
Trim(leading 'http:' from name)
```

I am new to sql so would love your thoughts.

Comment: Your answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try it first like this

SELECT
   TRIM (
      LEADING 'http:'
      FROM
         name
   ) From Table

but in general your answer is correct